# Conditional statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to execute two different instructions when a condition is verified but I get an error. Here is my sample code 
`bool <= 0;
d<=-d;
 when d>0;`

In this example, if d>0, I want to affect the value 0 to bool and the -d value to d. How can I proceed without using an if statement inside a process.

Comment: With VHDL-2008 you can use the `when` syntax within processes. But, you can still assign only one signal per `when`. What is wrong with using an `if`?

Comment: A ternary operator can only assign values to one signal or variable.

Comment: I want to execute these two instructions without using a process, in a parallel way. But I discover that there is only one way to do that, the subsequential (process) way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

- If `d` and `bool` are to be buffered with registers, than a construct with `if` inside a `process` would be appropriate.
- If not, then concurrent  assignments with `when` are the way to go. Then you would need different signals for the incoming and the outgoing `d`.